# Building wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch (setup.py) ...installing multiperson and neural mesh renderer doesn't work for pytorch 1.6

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, pose-estimation

I am trying to install a github repo named [multiperson](https://github.com/JiangWenPL/multiperson) for PyTorch 1.6 and I get the following error. How can I make it work for PyTorch 1.6?

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research$ cd phosa/
(base) mona@mona:~/research/phosa$ mkdir -p external
(base) mona@mona:~/research/phosa$ git clone https://github.com/JiangWenPL/multiperson.git external/multiperson
Cloning into 'external/multiperson'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 752, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (752/752), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (566/566), done.
remote: Total 752 (delta 189), reused 723 (delta 173), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (752/752), 48.29 MiB | 46.26 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (189/189), done.
(base) mona@mona:~/research/phosa$ pip install external/multiperson/neural_renderer
Processing ./external/multiperson/neural_renderer
Building wheels for collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
  Building wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/mona/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-nl9m5bw0
       cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/
  Complete output (210 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/load_obj.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/perspective.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/vertices_to_faces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/visibility.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/get_points_from_angles.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/look.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/projection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/rasterize.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/save_obj.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/look_at.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/lighting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/mesh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  copying neural_renderer/renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda
  copying neural_renderer/cuda/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda
  running build_ext
  building 'neural_renderer.cuda.load_textures' extension
  creating /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
  creating /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda
  Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build.ninja...
  Compiling objects...
  Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
  [1/2] /usr/bin/nvcc -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/mona/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c -c /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.cu -o /tmp/pip-req-

    copying neural_renderer/look_at.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
    copying neural_renderer/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
    copying neural_renderer/lighting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
    copying neural_renderer/mesh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
    copying neural_renderer/renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda
    copying neural_renderer/cuda/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda
    running build_ext
    building 'neural_renderer.cuda.load_textures' extension
    creating /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer
    creating /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda
    Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build.ninja...
    Compiling objects...
    Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
    [1/2] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o.d -pthread -B /home/mona/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/mona/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c -c /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp -o /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    FAILED: /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o
    c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o.d -pthread -B /home/mona/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/mona/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c -c /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp -o /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Parallel.h:149,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/cloneable.h:5,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
    /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ParallelOpenMP.h:84: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
       84 | #pragma omp parallel for if ((end - begin) >= grain_size)
          |
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp: In function ‘at::Tensor load_textures(at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, int, int)’:
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
          |                                       ^
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
       17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
          |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:28:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
       28 |     CHECK_INPUT(image);
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:5,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
    /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:268:30: note: declared here
      268 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
          |                              ^~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:23: error: ‘AT_CHECK’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘DCHECK’?
       15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
          |                       ^~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
       17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
          |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:28:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
       28 |     CHECK_INPUT(image);
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
          |                                       ^
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
       17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
          |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:29:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
       29 |     CHECK_INPUT(faces);
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:5,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
    /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:268:30: note: declared here
      268 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
          |                              ^~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
          |                                       ^
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
       17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
          |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:30:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
       30 |     CHECK_INPUT(is_update);
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:5,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
    /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:268:30: note: declared here
      268 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
          |                              ^~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
          |                                       ^
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
       17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
          |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
    /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:31:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
       31 |     CHECK_INPUT(textures);
          |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:5,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:4,
                     from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                     from /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
    /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:268:30: note: declared here
      268 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
          |                              ^~~~
    [2/2] /usr/bin/nvcc -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/mona/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c -c /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.cu -o /tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -std=c++14
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1515, in _run_ninja_build
        env=env)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        cmdclass = {'build_ext': BuildExtension}
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 163, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 87, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 649, in build_extensions
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
        _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 208, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 478, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
        with_cuda=with_cuda)
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1233, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
        error_prefix='Error compiling objects for extension')
      File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1529, in _run_ninja_build
        raise RuntimeError(message)
    RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of neural-renderer-pytorch
  Moving to /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neural_renderer/
   from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~eural_renderer
  Moving to /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neural_renderer_pytorch-1.1.3.dist-info/
   from /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~eural_renderer_pytorch-1.1.3.dist-info
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/mona/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ma51z6r7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ul8nk1jn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mona/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/neural-renderer-pytorch Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.6.0'
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ nvidia-smi
Sun Dec  6 16:36:36 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8    21W /  N/A |   1546MiB /  7982MiB |      8%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to change all `AT_CHECK` in neural mesh renderer to `TORCH_CHECK`

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/phosa/external/multiperson/neural_renderer$ rg AT_CHECK
neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp
15:#define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
16:#define CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x) AT_CHECK(x.is_contiguous(), #x " must be contiguous")

neural_renderer/cuda/create_texture_image_cuda.cpp
13:#define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
14:#define CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x) AT_CHECK(x.is_contiguous(), #x " must be contiguous")

neural_renderer/cuda/rasterize_cuda.cpp
69:#define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
70:#define CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x) AT_CHECK(x.is_contiguous(), #x " must be contiguous")
```

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/phosa$ pip install external/multiperson/neural_renderer
Processing ./external/multiperson/neural_renderer
Building wheels for collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
  Building wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch: filename=neural_renderer_pytorch-1.1.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=6321659 sha256=5e2f4afc2346a90c5cd804b226dd7c424ab95f477aad67f2ca3f15530484fbc6
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-_rf6c5ld/wheels/c7/1b/84/10bf7a286a267887d8c7d382677c292cf18e1bba4e2508ed33
Successfully built neural-renderer-pytorch
Installing collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
  Attempting uninstall: neural-renderer-pytorch
    Found existing installation: neural-renderer-pytorch 1.1.3
    Uninstalling neural-renderer-pytorch-1.1.3:
      Successfully uninstalled neural-renderer-pytorch-1.1.3
Successfully installed neural-renderer-pytorch-1.1.3
```